# Singular function that is Holder for all $\alpha<1$

Tags: measure-theory, cantor-set, holder-spaces, singular-measures

I am asking for an example of a singular continuous function that is Holder for all $\alpha<1$.

We know that such function cannot be Lipschitz, otherwise it is absolutely continuous.

We also know that a standard Cantor function is singular, but it is not Holder for $\alpha>\log 2/\log 3$.

So I am guessing if there is some kind of "fat Cantor function" that works.

Comment: what does "singular continuous function" mean?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_function